# Why do we add 1 to the precision when multiplying two numeric columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql), when two `numeric` columns in a database are multiplied the resulting value has one more precision than the sum of the two operands. That is, if we multiply `numeric(p1, s1) * numeric(p2, s2)` we end up getting `numeric(p1 + p2 + 1, s1 + s2)`. I can't see why they would need to add one. Even in the case of multiplying `999.999 * 999.999` it would not overflow to need the additional +1 precision.

I can't see any common scenario where the additional +1 would help. If we added a small number to the result of two maximum numeric values then yes it would carry to the next digit, but the formula for the precision of an addition already accounts for this. The additional 1 precision can only hurt when we consider truncation into maximum 38, it can never help give a more precise result.

Is this a completely arbitrary "safety buffer" that got added even though it is never needed? [SQL extra precision when calculating, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184122/sql-extra-precision-when-calculating-why) mentions that there might be some edge case, but doesn't elaborate on what the edge cases actually are so it is only a guess. I personally can't think of any possible edge case.

Comment: Aside from the documentation.. have you tested this?